# How related hibernate @Size max and oracle varchar in bytes

Tags: oracle, hibernate, size, byte

I have @Size annotation of field:

```
@Column(name = "SHARE_PART_STR")
@Size(max = 10)
private String shareStr;
```

This field declared in Oracle as:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
(
  SHARE_PART_STR  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
)
```

How @Size(max = 10) related to 10 BYTE? Did hibernate tries to save VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) to VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)? Is this desired correct behaviour? Or is it incorrect to use VARCHAR2(... BYTE) with hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `NVARCHAR2`, if this is a field where non-ascii characters, especially UTF-8 are used.